# How to draw a 3D super-ellipse with OpenGL in c++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

For creating a 3D Sphere with OpenGL in C++, I use this function:

```
glutWireSphere(GLdouble radius, GLint slices, GLint stacks);
```

My code runs very well and shows a wire sphere rotating.
But I don't know how to write a function that draws a super-ellipse.

I know the formula of a super-ellipse:

[image: super-ellipse]

How can I draw a 3D super-ellipse using this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `s1=s2=1` you still can use `glutWireSphere`. Apply transformation matrix so `(1,0,0)` is tranformed into `(rx,0,0)`, `(0,1,0)` into `(0,ry,0)`, and `(0,0,1)` into `(0,0,rz)`. Then simply draw identity sphere with glutWireSphere(1, ..., ...). I think `glScalef(rx,ry,rz)` will do the trick.

For general case, you need to generate geometry yourself with glBegin/glEnd or glDrawArrays. Take a look at [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31308/algorithm-for-creating-spheres) for some clues on that.

One of things you need to change:

> When you're done, normalize all of the vertices to smooth out the surface.
>   If you don't do this, you'll just get a higher-res icosahedron instead of a sphere.

Instead of normalization, convert `(x,y,z)` into `(phi, theta, R)`, then calculate new `(x',y',z')` by substituting `phi` and `theta` into your equations. You should perform this step also for initial icosahedron, before any subdividings take place